# Practical uses for silverlight against ajax/javascript

Tags: silverlight

Hi
Please give clear practical uses where silverlight must be used, with some practical example, where we must go for silverlight.

Comment: Lots of information on the web about this...in a nutshell...SL for apps, typical web FW's for sites or if you care about a more cross platform approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, personally, think, at least for right now, the main reason for a shift to Silverlight is the visuals.

Lots of the visual stuff is a lot easier to do on silverlight. But you have to think not everyone has silverlight right now, so it may be better to stick with ajax/javascript for now.

But the good news is you can use ajax in silverlight so its basically the developers choice and what your most comfortable with.

Silverlight is more of a flash competitor then an ajax one.

[info1](http://www.nikhilk.net/Ajax-vs-Silverlight-and-NET.aspx)
[info2](http://www.plaveb.com/blog/difference-between-ajax-and-microsoft-silverlight)